# SQL WHERE Expression in CASE clause

Tags: sql

I want to fetch data from a table `Item` that has the two fields `name` and `nullable_name`, the second one can be empty.

Now I want to add a filter string, so that only results will get fetched that contain that string (in the `name` field if `nullable_name` is null, and in the `nullable_name` field if it is present). So I want one of two WHERE expressions to take place, depending on the situation.

What I tried but didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM Item
WHERE
CASE 
    WHEN Item.nullable_name IS NULL THEN (Item.name LIKE '%filter%')
    ELSE (Item.nullable_name LIKE '%filter%')
END
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: Familiarize yourself with [coalesce()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp), [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [subselects](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/).  Or simply break your "where" filter into two clauses .

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp Have you tried the "IN" operator?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `coalesce()`:

```
where coalesce(item.nullable_name, item.name) like '%filter%'
```

`coalesce()` is a function that returns the first non-`NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try
Where isnull(item.nullable_name, item.name) like '%filter%'